# Vim: open a file based on a git command

Tags: neovim

Goal: map `<localleader>n` to open `"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/notes.md"`

I know how to do mappings, and the above git command works fine on the command line. Marrying the two together in vim has been surprisingly hard.

I tried running vim commands like this: `:e system("$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/notes.md")`, but that just opens a file called "system(".

I'll take a vimscript solution, though a lua solution is slightly more preferable.

Comment: backticks should work, e.g. `:e \`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\`/notes.md`

Comment: @MarcoLucidi thanks for the insight! I posted the answer that worked for me based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

This line in my lua init file works. Backticks are the secret sauce:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(
  'n',
  '<localleader>n',
  ':e `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/notes.md<CR>',
  { noremap = true, silent = true }
)
```